# How to get Excel Worksheet List Activate Toolbar?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have many excel workbooks with many worksheets in them. It is always difficult to navigate between them. I found a VBA macro that shows the list of them using Macro. Here is the macro.

```
Sub SheetMenu()
Application.CommandBars("Workbook tabs").ShowPopup
End Sub
```

When I use this macro, it shows the list of tabs as below, and surprisingly, if there are more worksheets, there is an option at the end '**More Sheets**'.

[image: excel switch between tabs]

When I click on that, I get this really handy Activate Worksheet toolbar, with entire list of worksheets.

[image: activate excel worksheets toolbar]

How do I get this without macro? Is it part of one of the toolbars or commands? (If I can get this toolbar, I don't need to use macro at all). Please help. Thanks.

Comment: right click on the "arrows" thingy to the left of the tabs

Comment: wow, so simple, can you add it as a answer and I can select it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

converting my comment to answer,

*right click on the "arrows" thingy to the left of the tabs* (yellow hightlight):

[image]